# What are the steps involved in the execution of the program which generates the subset of a given set (using recursion)?

Tags: c++, recursion

Program for subsets of a set

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> subset;
int n = 3;
void search(int k) {
    if (k == n) {
        cout << "{ ";
        for (auto x : subset) {
            cout << x;
            if ( x != subset.back() )
                cout << ", ";
        }
        cout << " } ";
    }
    else {
        search(k+1);           //**Explanation**
        subset.push_back(k);   // **for** 
        search(k+1);           //**these** 
        subset.pop_back();     //**statements**
    }
}

int main() {
    int k = 0;
    search(k);
}
```

I can't understand the code given in the **else** section.

o/p:-

```
 {  } { 2 } { 1 } { 1, 2 } { 0 } { 0, 2 } { 0, 1 } { 0, 1, 2 }
```

Comment: why you cannot understand it? What exactly is not clear?

Comment: I cannot understand the part in which k is pushed back in the subset and then again we call search() and then we use that pop_back() to pop out the number from the subset.

Comment: Try stepping through the code, line by line, in a debugger, and stepping into the recursive calls.

Comment: subset is temporary variable and function search uses it to output data. pop_back needs to remove value of current recursive step.

Comment: btw where did you get this code from? imho code that comes with zero documentation (I dont mean comments in the code) is worthless. Instead of reverse engineering this one you will probably learn more by writing it yourself

Comment: I got this code from the book "Competitive Programmer’s Handbook by
Antti Laaksonen".

Comment: If an answer resolves your issue, please consider to accept it

Answer (score 1):

With this kind of issue, sometime, better way is to take a pen and a sheet and to "execute" software by hand:

- call `search(0)`  (`subset = { }`)

  - call `search(1)`  (`subset = { }`)

    - call `search(2)`   (`subset = { }`)

      - call `search(3)`  (`subset = { }`)

        - print `subset`   (`subset = { }`)
      - push back 2 in subset (`subset = { 2 }`)
      - call `search(3)`  (`subset = { 2 }`)

        - print `subset`   (`subset = { 2 }`)
      - remove last element (`subset = { }`)

        > When you come back to `search(1)`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(2)`
    - push back 1 in subset (`subset = { 1 }`)
    - call `search(2)` (`subset = { 1 }`)

      - call `search(3)` (`subset = { 1 }`)

        - print `subset`  (`subset = { 1 }`)
      - push back 2 in subset (`subset = { 1, 2 }`)
      - call `search(3)` (`subset = { 1, 2 }`)

        - print `subset`  (`subset = { 1, 2 }`)
      - remove last element (`subset = { 1 }`)

        > When you come back to `search(1)`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(2)`
    - remove last element (`subset = { }`)

      > When you come back to `search(0)`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(1)`
  - push back 0 in subset  (`subset = { 0 }`)
  - call `search(1)`  (`subset = { 0 }`)

    - call `search(2)`  (`subset = { 0 }`)

      - call `search(3)`  (`subset = { 0 }`)

        - print `subset`   (`subset = { 0 }`)
      - push back 2 in subset (`subset = { 0, 2 }`)
      - call `search(3)` (`subset = { 0, 2 }`)

        - print `subset`  (`subset = { 0, 2 }`)
      - remove last element (`subset = { 0 }`)

        > When you come back to `search(1)`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(2)`
    - push back 1 in subset (`subset = { 0, 1 }`)
    - call `search(2)`(`subset = { 0, 1 }`)

      - call `search(3)`(`subset = { 0, 1 }`)

        - print `subset` (`subset = { 0, 1 }`)
      - push back 2 in subset (`subset = { 0, 1, 2 }`)
      - call `search(3)` (`subset = { 0, 1, 2 }`)

        - print `subset`  (`subset = { 0, 1, 2 }`)
      - remove last element (`subset = { 0, 1 }`)

        > When you come back to `search(1)`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(2)`
    - remove last element (`subset = { 0 }`)

      > When you come back to `search(0)`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(1)`
  - remove last element (`subset = { }`)

    > When you come back to `main`, `subset` still in same state as before call of `search(0)`

With that, we can see that `push_back` is for populate `subset` and `pop_back` is for cleaning/undoing action maid by this step. Indeed, you use a global variable, used also by previous call of this function. In this algorithm, you have to clean it to restore state of this variable for caller. It would be different if you pass `subset` by value.

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but your answer is really satisfying. Once again, Thank You.

Comment: On SO, when an answer is satisfying, OP has to consider to accept it (if answer completly answer to question, of course)